# Why do I see Questions with suggested edits but no pending suggested edits in queue

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, live-refresh

I see questions that I want to edit but they show edit (1). I can select it and see the edit. The two times I have seen this, I have already hit my daily limit to approve the selected edit. My question is, why don't I see any suggested edits in the suggested edit queue?

I have seen this where there were no edit queue shown and now I saw it where it showed 13 in the edit queue, so I waited about 5 minutes and refreshed the page. The pending suggested edits went away but the edit (1) still showed. See below.

[image]

Here is another one. I had to zoom out to get the whole thing in the image.

[image]

I looked at [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)  but didn't see the explanation there.

EDIT: for the above image.
1. It shows 13 edits in queue and edit (1) for the question.
2. I refresh the page and the 13 edits queue “red box” goes away.
3. The question still shows edit (1).
4. I go to the review page and see zero for the suggested edit queue.
5. I go back to the question and it still shows edit (1).

Comment: [Blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: Yes, I click on it and it brings it up, but why isn't it shown in the suggested edit queue. There is no "box" with a number by the review link at the top of the page. And if i go to review I see zero for the suggested edit queue. What does "fully resolved" mean?

Comment: Ah you must have seen my comment before I changed it (I reread your question and realized it was irrelevant).  That orange box doesn't update realtime.

Comment: Okay, so the red box isn't live refreshed.  Does the edit link (edit (1)) refresh?

Comment: I would think so since edits to posts are pushed to the post itself.  So once you click that banner "This post has been edited", it will go away.

Comment: So how about the second image.  It shows 13 edits in queue and edit (1) for the question.  I refresh and the 13 edits queue “red box” goes away.  But the question still shows edit (1). I go to the review page and see zero for the suggested edit queue.  I go back to the question and it still shows edit (1).

Comment: The review page is also not live refreshed.  The post itself is live refreshed so that's the important indicator.